# how to convert denary to binary by repeatedly dividing by 2?

Tags: python, binary, iteration

Im stuck on a problem where I have to write a function that converts a denary number into a binary number using the repeated division by two algorithm. Steps Include:

-The number to be converted is divided by two.

-The remainder from the division is the next binary digit. Digits are added to the front of the sequence.

-The result is truncated so that the input to the next division by two is always an integer.

-The algorithm continues until the result is 0.

Please click the link below to see what the output should be like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pifUO.png

This is My code so far:

```
def dentobi(user):
  denary = user
  divide = user / 2
  remainder = user % 2
  binary = remainder
  
  while user != 0:
    print("Denary:", denary)
    print("Divide by 2:", divide)
    print("Remainder:", remainder)
    print("Binary:", binary)
    result = str(binary) + str(remainder)
    print(result)
    
user = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
dentobi(user)
```

My output when a number doesn't have remainder is:

Please enter a number: 20
Denary: 20
Divide by 2: 10.0
Remainder: 0
Binary: 0
Output when the number does have a remainder:

Please enter a number: 20
Denary: 20
Divide by 2: 10.0
Remainder: 0
Binary: 0

This is one part of what I wanted to happen however I need this to iterate over and over again until the actual value reaches zero.

I need some help in coding the remainder to go in the front each time, appreciate the advice.

Comment: `using the repeated division by two algorithm` ->move the operations inside the loop. `The algorithm continues until the result is 0` -> change the loop condition so you evaluate the result, not the input

Comment: You appear to have an infinite loop whenever *user* is non-zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this. Here's one:

```
def dentobi(n):
    result = ''
    while n > 0:
        result =  str(n % 2) + result
        n //= 2
    return result or '0'


print(dentobi(26))
```

**Output:**

```
11010
```

**Note:**

This will **not** work for negative values

Comment: Great, makes much more sense. Thanks.